# What is this type of graph representation matrix called?

Tags: data-structures, graph, adjacency-matrix

In an algorithms course quite some years ago, I came across an interesting graph representation. It is basically a path matrix, but with extra information. Each cell `Aij` contains the (possibly empty) list of vertices adjacent to `i` that you can pass through to reach `j`.

For example, the directed graph informally represented as:

(Z → X)    (Z → Y)    (X → W)    (Y → W)

gets the following matrix:
[image]
When maintaining a matrix like this you have the advantage of knowing not only *if* there is a path from `i` to `j`, but *what* all possible paths are.

But I can't for the life of me find any reference to this representation on the web. What's it called?

Comment: Seems like a variation of adjacency matrix

Comment: I would say it's more like a path matrix, in that you can determine reachability with a single lookup. It also has the characteristics of an adjacency-*list*. You can get all vertices adjacent to `i` if you take the union of the cells in row `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and a hint from an old teacher, I came upon the [path reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_algorithm#Path_reconstruction) section of the Wikipedia article about the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_algorithm). They store the 'next node' in the shortest path between `i` and `j` in the `Aij` cell of what they call a:

*next matrix*

In a [set of slides](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/courses/12/esslli12/GraphsAlgs.pdf) by what appears to be a colleague of mine, it is called a:

*distance-next table*

in the same context. Granted, they are talking about storing the information of the shortest paths only. Of course, for that purpose it suffices to store only one node(-index) per cell. Neither of these sources is citing any scientific publication. But after searching for a long while, I strongly feel that the matrix representation from my original question was never officially named. So, I dub thee:

**path-next matrix**

If anyone can cite a scientific publication that says otherwise, I'd still be happy to accept their answer over my own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's called **adjacency-list matrix**. See http://www.dmi.usherb.ca/~hlaoui/th.pdf or [search in Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22adjacency+list+matrix%22)

Comment: No, I don't think so. From what I understand from that paper (which is not particularly well presented), they simply take a path matrix and sort of 'append' adjacency list information into each cell. It feels a bit inelegant and I don't really see the advantage over maintaining both structures separately. --- The kind of matrix I'm talking about tells you *how* you can get from A to B. That information is missing from the adjacency-list matrix.